# Hide list items with undefined strings

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using Wikipedia API in my project. I loop through an object to display an article and its description below like that.

[image]

Most of **li** (articles) display properly, but some of them show **undefined**. Like that

[image]

What i want is to hide **li**s which show **undefined**. I wrote the code

```
// Check if some articles are undefined if so hide them
if (articleAuthor === "undefined") {
  $('.articleItem').html('');
}
```

But it does not help. **$('.articleItem')** is dynamically create list item.

[Codepen Project Link](http://codepen.io/nazimkazim/pen/YWjALR)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try comparing with `undefined` without quotes? `undefined` is an object in javascript

Comment: `if (articleAuthor === "undefined")`  means is `articleAuthor ` equal to `undefined` with type `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do 2 things here:

First, switch your `if (articleAuthor === "undefined")` with `if (typeof articleAuthor === "undefined")`.

Second, switch your `$('.articleItem').html('');` with `$('.articleItem').last().html('');`

You could also wrap the `domCache.$wikiArticlesList.append` in that if (`if (typeof articleAuthor === "undefined")`) and that will not create the item at all.

Comment: Thanks i appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to remove the element:

```
if (articleAuthor === undefined) { //remove the quote from undefined
  $('.articleItem').remove();
}
```

But the preceding method would remove all articleItem, and the best way to do is check for not undefined and create the elments:

```
if(articleAuthor !== undefined){
   //create element logic here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This selector here:

```
$('.articleItem')
```

will return a list of elements with class 'articleItem', you have to cycle it to change the html of all items

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)** to check `undefined` or not

```
if (typeof articleAuthor === "undefined") {
  $('.articleItem').html('');
}
```

Comment: @NZMAI : glad to help